# Visual Studio 2022 text editor losing color syntax after casting interface

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Entire code goes white after I cast an interface like

```
let object : someInterface = <someInterface> someUnknownHapiRequestPayload
```

[print of text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JBff.png)

Already tried common things like: update VS22, restore defaults, change text editor and theme settings, recreate the project and other basic things like that

Also, if someone knows how can I cast an unknown type data (that is already validated to my interface schema) to assert its type and instance a new object in a way I can acess its properties like:

```
object.someInterfacePropertie = someFunction(object.someInterfacePropertie)
```

This also would be appreciated and possibly solve my problem. I'm new to typescript. Thank you

**EDIT:**

I was able to bypass it by casting my interface in an alternative way:

```
let object: someInterface = someUnknownHapiRequestPayload as someInterface
```

This way it won't bug the text editor. But still, the first one being a valid way, I will report this as a problem for Microsoft.

Comment: Same here.  Do you have a public  error report of this?  Can I vote for it?

Comment: @JDC To be honest you, I forgot to open the issue. So, I tested the problem again today and it persists. I'm sharing with you the link of the problem I reported right now: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Text-editor-losing-color-syntax-after-ca/10361822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Seems like there was already an issue reported, and Microsoft fixed it. It will be released in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6 preview 4.

More info on that here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/TypeScript-Syntax-Highlight-Broken/10274299